# HTTP GET download time varies greatly between clients

Tags: http, post, download, get, transfer

We have implemented an HTTP file transfer in C on an embedded device using a TI microprocessor.
We can successfully POST and GET a file to and from the system.
When testing the GET using a 2Meg file using various Clients I am getting a big difference in download speed.
On an Apple Mac, iOs device, or my Xamarin UWP application the file will download in about 3 seconds.
Using any browser on a PC, or using Postman on a PC or Android device it takes over a minute.
I sniffed the situation on Wireshark and I find the difference is that for each packet (1024 bytes in this case),  the fast system clients send the ACK in about 20 uS,  and on the slow systems the ACK takes about 40mS.  so 2,000 packets X 40mS is 80 seconds.
Would anyone have an idea what could cause this?
I guess it would be related to something on our HTTP Host since all these clients take about the same time downloading files from conventional Hosts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like it's related to the client using Nagle's algorithm.  If I shut that off on the client side then the ACK delay is eliminated and the download is very fast.  If I understand correctly, Apple uses a different implementation so that would account for the fast performance on Apple devices.  I'm still fighting to shut off Nagle's on an Android device as it appears TCPSocet.NoDelay = true;  is not doing the job for Xamarin Android build.